# Paperclip and amazon s3 - Connection refused, port 443

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to setup paperclip with s3 on development but get:

`Connection refused - connect(2) for "bjjbase.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com" port 443`

My aws.yml:

```
development:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxx
```

IAM User with these tokens has `AmazonS3FullAccess`

development.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => 'bjjbase.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => 'bjjbase.com'
  }
```

Not sure if it's important but my machine is in Warsaw, Poland.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean. `nslookup bjjbase.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` answers correctly, so looks like it works.

Comment: I think you should include access_key_id and secret_access_key in your  credentials like so:  `:s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']`